# java serialization causes utfdataformatexception

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to serialize a number of objects to a file. In particular, when i try to write

```
public void execute(PipelineContext context) throws Exception {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test_audit_trail2.objects");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

        BigInteger rho = (BigInteger) context.get("rho");
        BigInteger p = (BigInteger) context.get("p");
        BigInteger xS = (BigInteger) context.get("xs");
        BigInteger zSBar = (BigInteger)context.get("zsbar");

        int nS  = (Integer) context.get("ns");
        P2PShuffler ownShuff = (P2PShuffler) context.get("shuffler");
        HexCryptor cryptor = (HexCryptor) context.get("cryptor");
        String[] PRPrimePrimeBar = (String []) context.get("pr_prime_prime_bar");
        P2PAuditTrailGenerator ownATG = (P2PAuditTrailGenerator) context.get("p2p_audit_trail_generator");
        int kS = (Integer) context.get("ks");

        oos.writeObject(rho);
        oos.writeObject(p); 
        oos.writeObject(xS);
        oos.writeObject(zSBar);
        oos.writeObject(ownShuff);
        oos.writeObject(cryptor);
        oos.writeObject(PRPrimePrimeBar);
        oos.writeObject(ownATG);
        oos.writeObject(nS);
        oos.writeObject(kS);
```

This happen ok, all the writeObject succeed and I close the corresponding streams faithfully. However, when i try to reconstruct back all the objects by calling readObject(), I encountered the `UTFDataFormatException`

```
java.io.UTFDataFormatException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFSpan(ObjectInputStream.java:3081)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3006)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2819)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1050)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:614)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:808)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1564)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1315)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(ObjectInputStream.java:1911)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1873)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at edu.foo.peer.pipeline.AuditTrailCheckStageTest.setUp
```

After commenting out the `readObject` and `writeObject` one by one, it seems that the leaving `P2PAuditTrailGenerator` out of this allows me to read in all the objects successfully. Looking at this class, it seems that there aren't String related objects.

```
public class P2PAuditTrailGenerator implements Serializable {

    private int num;
    private BigInteger phi;
    private BigInteger rho;
    /**
     * @param   auditTrailSecretKeys    The secret keys used for audit trail
     */
    private BigInteger[] auditTrailSecretKeys;
    private BigInteger[] encAuditTrails;
    private Random rnd;

    public BigInteger [] getAuditTrailSecretKeys(){
        return auditTrailSecretKeys;
    }


    public P2PAuditTrailGenerator(int num, BigInteger rho, BigInteger phi) {
        this.num = num;
        this.phi = phi;
        this.rho = rho;
        auditTrailSecretKeys = new BigInteger[num];
        encAuditTrails = new BigInteger[num];
        rnd = new Random();

    }

    public BigInteger[] generateATs() {

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            //assuming the security parameter is always 512 or 1024;
            auditTrailSecretKeys[i] = new BigInteger(200, rnd).mod(phi);
            encAuditTrails[i] = rho.modPow(auditTrailSecretKeys[i], phi);

        }
        return encAuditTrails;
    }
}
```

Am id-ing the wrong class or if not, what's wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Hey have you solved this issue? I am facing the same, need help. My class is having no-argument constructor as Chris said.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you've declared P2PAuditTrailGenerator to be serializable but it doesn't have a no-argument constructor.  Everything else looks OK.

Comment: why does a no argument constructor matter?

Comment: Serialization requires there be a no-arg constructor on the class or one of its parents.  Wouldn't hurt to add it to see if it improves things.  Otherwise you'll need to go through and comment out the lines in readObject and writeObject to see which of the instance vars are causing the problem.

Comment: You're guessing all right. `P2PAuditTrailGenerator` does *not* need a no-args constructor, but its nearest non-serializable base class does, and if it doesn't have one you get a different exception: `IllegalClassException`.